# python support for earlier version of windows

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, executable, platform

I am developing a desktop application for windows using pyqt5. I am using python version 3.9. I am not sure about that when i will convert it into exe, will it run on windows 7,8,8.1. Its not commercial. Its a specific purpose-based application. I will convert it into exe and give it to the client. I want my app to run on any version of windows (7+).

I searched for python support for windows went to official python website there I found the support for different versions of python for windows eg this python version cannot run on windows XP or earlier this line was written with python versions 3.5+ but that's for the installation setup not sure if the same thing that after converting to exe the support will also be same. I want that which version of python should i use to build my application such that it runs on windows 7 and higher.

Comment: From what I understand if you need windows 7 support you should be using py 3.8.

Comment: You need 3.7 <= Python <= 3.8,6 so as to support both Windows 7 and PyQt5.

Comment: Look at this project: https://github.com/adang1345/PythonWin7  There's a description of how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ we can see

[image]

Note how the compatibility notice changed from

> Note that Python 3.8.6 cannot be used on **Windows XP** or earlier.

to

> Note that Python 3.9.0 cannot be used on **Windows 7** or earlier.

So python 3.8.6 seems to be the last version that officially supported windows 7